# Mule parameters in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, variables, mule

I'm trying to query two databases `f102` which is MySQL and `f100` which is SQL Server.

The query to the MySQL server works but the SQL Server connector doesn't like the  "#[header:INBOUND:company] as company" and throws:

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Too many parameters: expected 0, was given 1
>   at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.fillStatement(QueryRunner.java:176)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:392)
>   at org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.SelectSqlStatementStrategy.executeStatement(SelectSqlSt      atementStrategy.java:80)
>   + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Is there any differences between calling MySQL and SQL Server when it comes to invoke variables and parameters in the query?

```
<jdbc:connector name="db_conn_f102" dataSource-ref="f102" pollingFrequency="5000" doc:name="Database" validateConnections="false">
    <jdbc:query key="read" value="SELECT ID , #[header:INBOUND:company] as company FROM AcTr"/>
</jdbc:connector>

<jdbc:connector name="db_conn_f100" dataSource-ref="f100" pollingFrequency="5000" doc:name="Database" validateConnections="false">
    <jdbc:query key="readickr" value="SELECT ID, #[header:INBOUND:company] as company FROM AcTr"/>
</jdbc:connector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in variable resolution in queries as far as database type is concerned.

I reckon the issue is that the generate SQL query is not syntactically correct for SQL Server. Like: is it legal to use a bound variable in the `SELECT` part of a query with SQL Server?

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't manage to fully understand it. Do you think it's impossible to use variables with MS SQL server?

Comment: I don't know: I've never used JDBC with MS SQL Server so I don't know if it's possible to use bound variables in the `SELECT` part not the `WHERE` clause, where it should obviously work.

Comment: Regardless of the DBMS you cannot use bound variables in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: It's strange because the  "#[header:INBOUND:company] as company" statement works with MySQL but not with MS SQLsrv and I want to use it for marking up the data with the company tag. If this is not working I think I need to manipulate the CSV-file which is produced instead but I think injecting company tag in the SELECT would be easier.

Comment: You're basically passing a value to the SQL engine so it can give it back to you: I'm sure you can review your flow to select only one column and avoid this altogether.

Comment: I've tried it with SQL Server using jTDS driver. It doesn't throw an exception but doesn't return the fields specified in the variable either. Instead it shows a list of maps like `[{=field1, field2,...},...]` where *field1, field2*, etc are the name of the fields stored in the variable.

Comment: Problem solved, I changed to jTDS driver and it made my day! Now it works! Thank YOU!